# Internet Explorer form input problem

Tags: html, debugging, internet-explorer-7

I'm having a ton of problems with every version of IE, one of which is that IE7 won't register input in this text input field.

http://www.flightm8.com/redesign

I'm a bit nervous about posting the link since the site looks a mess and doesn't function properly in any version of IE at the moment, and it is still quite a way off being ready for public consumption. But if anyone can shed any light on this particular problem I'd very much appreciate it.

So the question is: What is causing this problem in IE7?

Update: I've also added an additional textfield at the bottom of the page to try and rule out any CSS wierdness that might be causing the problem.

```
    <form method="post" action="nowhere.php">
        <input type='text' name='test' value='testing' />
    </form>
```

And I still can't enter any text, or select the text that is in there. I'm wondering now if it's a problem caused by running a standalone version of IE7 and IE6.
thanks
-t

Comment: <!-- MICROSOFT, I F**KING HATE YOU FOR MAKING ME DO THIS --> .. I'm still laughing :)

Comment: ah... um.... as I said, not quite ready for public consumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the function causing problem is this one :

```
function modalAlert
```

the call that need to be debugged is this one :

```
modalAlert("NO SELECTIONS");
```

in

```
function findRoutes
```

the line that bug is :

```
$("#dialog").css("top", dTop);
```

first, you should avoid iframes when you can, why don't you do :

```
var message = $('<div></div>').load('/modal/"+modalpage);
```

instead of crappy code like this :

```
var iframe = "<iframe id='modal_frame' width='533' height='292' src='/modal/"+modalpage+"' >You didn't give me any information</iframe>"
```

If you don't need iframes, don't use them !

```
$('body').append(message);
```

I have IE7 on win xp (native), I was able to enter text but after a freeze (when you add all those markers), then when entering text and clicking on "find routes", there's a bug that i just explained to you ...

Comment: thanks for the tip. So I guess it is the standalone version I'm using. Bugger.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine it is because the input box doesn't have a 'name' field, which is used when posting form data.

Comment: Seems the W3C would agree... "Definition and Usage
The name attribute specifies a name for an input element.

The name attribute is used to identify form data after it has been submitted to the server, or to reference form data using JavaScript on the client side.

Note: Only form elements with a name attribute will have their values passed when submitting a form." - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_name.asp

Comment: Well spotted, but I've made that amendment and it's still not taking any input. Im wondering if it's because I'm running a standalone version of IE7. Have you managed to actually enter text into the text field on IE7?